# lsqlin lambda interpretation

Tags: matlab, optimization

Ok so i have been using lsqlin to solve a constrained linear least-squares problem given by the following matrix A, where A=M(:,1:end-1) and b=M(:,end), and Pxyz =[0.5000,0.9000].

```
    M =

           -0.9000         0    0.3600
            0.9000         0    1.2600
                 0   -0.9000         0
                 0    0.9000    1.6200

    [X_result,resnorm,residual,exitflag,output,lambda]=...
lsqlin(eye(2),Pxyz, M(:,1:end-1), M(:,end),[],[],[],[],Pxyz,...
optimoptions('lsqlin','Display','off','MaxIter',100));
```

My problem is that the lambda.ineqlin seems to be incorrect (or I do not know how to interpret).

From this problem I would suspect that x(first variable) is bounded to -0.4<=x<=1.4 and y(second variable) bounded to 0<=y<=1.8, while the result of lambda.ineqlin is:

```
lambda.ineqlin =

     0
     0
     0
     0
```

What I am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question as I think this may be of relevance for someone.

lambda presents the Lagrange multipliers and not the direct bounds of the equations. In the presented example, the global maximum of the function is at X_result=Pxyz, which respects the constrains Ax<=b, leading to no active constrains and therefore null Lagrange multipliers.

In another view this result could also be obtained in a unconstrained linear least-squares, as the global maximum respects the constrains Ax<=b.